# When removing inside foreach, do we need to step back

Tags: java, foreach

Take this Java code:

```
for (ContactsReduced curContact : allcontacts) {
 ..........
 allcontacts.remove(curContact);
}
```

I do based on a condition a remove, will the foreach miss the next item in order, and do we need to step back(somehow)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That code will break with most collections - other than a few collections such as those in `java.util.concurrent`, modifying a collection while iterating over it isn't supported.

A few options:

- Obtain and use an iterator explicitly (call `iterator()` on the collection) instead of an enhanced for loop, and call `iterator.remove()` to remove an item
- Use a plain for loop, either moving forwards and stepping back after the removal or moving backwards from the end
- Maintain a separate list of items to remove, and then remove them *after* iterating

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that this "feature" is called fail-fast. It should help to navigate around when reading relevant Javadocs.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the section on iterators on the [collection interface tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html)

> Use Iterator instead of the for-each construct when you need to remove the current element. The for-each construct hides the iterator, so you cannot call remove. Therefore, the for-each construct is not usable for filtering.
>
> Note that Iterator.remove is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  al.add(i);
}
for(Integer x:al){
  al.remove(x);
  System.out.println(al);
}
```

Well, the question is interesting so I tried it in my system and this is wat i got.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely advised against to tamper with the collection while iterating it. I'm not sure if Java even allows it; it might throw an exception. I know C# does...

Answer (score 0):

Iterator will fail with ConcurrentModificationException. That's how collection framework is designed.